# How to Convert from String to Tuple in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I am retrieving  a record from DB getting the record as below

```
('("2014-02-21 07:10:40",ManualNo,184,vsp,AP10123456,aaaaa,Coconut-Na,5,10)',)
```

and I need to get the data as tuple like:

```
("2014-02-21 07:10:40",ManualNo,184,vsp,AP10123456,aaaaa,Coconut-Na,5,10)
```

without using split function and then want to get the individual values from it.

like

```
record[0] = 2014-02-21 07:10:40
record[1] = ManualNo
```

and so on...

Comment: Why oh why don't you use split?

Comment: How are you getting that record from the DB - could you show the code for that? I get a feeling this might be a wild goose chase...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply split the string over the comma:

```
data = ('("2014-02-21 07:10:40",ManualNo,184,vsp,AP10123456,aaaaa,Coconut-Na,5,10)',)
record = data[0].lstrip('(').rstrip(')').split(',')
```

Comment: We know how the retrieve by splitting the string but what I need is to convert the String into tuple. If we have comma in between the value it will not work.